# Conditional <br> for address format in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, line, tostring, break

I am formatting my application to show the address related to a specific work ticket.  Occasionally the address uses a second line.  I don't want to use the following:

```
<%: ticket.ADDRESS2 %><br />
```

In this scenario, if the object is null or empty I still get the break and then I have a large space that looks funny.

I thought I could generate my own string and then turn it into a literal with something like this:

```
string str = ((Object)ticket.ADDRESS2 != "").ToString();
string sAdd2 = str + <br />;
myLiteral.Text = sAdd2;
```

But that doesn't actually help me out if the Object is null or empty (in fact, I don't even know if it works at all.

So then I tried this:

```
public string sAdd2
    {
        get
        {
            Object oAdd2 = ticket.ADDRESS2;
            if (oAdd2 != null)
            {
                string sAdd2 = ((Object)ticket.ADDRESS2 != "").ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                string sAdd2 = ((Object)ticket.ADDRESS2 == "").ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

With this I get errors at the 'get' (not all code paths return a value).  I feel like I am going way out of the way to do a simple thing.  I just want to have my page show

Address Line 1 
Address Line 2 
City, State  ZIP

or

Address Line 1 
City, State  ZIP

Anyone have any pointers?  I've looked up "conditional breaks" but didn't get much of a useful return.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an if statement

```
<%if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ticket.ADDRESS2)) { %>

   <%: ticket.ADDRESS2 %><br />

<%} %>
```

Comment: Perfect.  This is exactly what I wanted.  So simple, I was over complicating it.  Thank you!!  (I also learned something about how the <% %> works in the HTML side!!

Comment: Excellent, glad I could help.  Be sure to accept this answer if it fixed your problem

Answer (score 1):

What I have done in the past – in an MVC project, but could easily be in code behind for WebForms – is:

```
var lines = new [] {
  contact.Name,
  contact.AddressLine1,
  contact.AddressLine2,
  contact.AddressLine3,
  contact.PostCode
};

var address = String.Join("<br/>", lines.Where(l => !String.IsNullOrWhitespace(l));
```

and then use the appropriate method to write out `address` as a raw string.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I will keep this bookmarked as a reference if my formatting needs get more complicated.  I used the other answer in my code though, because it worked perfect in my simple situation!

Answer (score 0):

Remove blank lines, then use [string.Join()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx) to add newlines.

```
// Get the address lines to be displayed
string[] lines = new string[]
{
   ticket.Address1,
   ticket.Address2,
   ticket.Address3,
   ticket.Address4,
   ticket.ZipCode,
};

// Remove blank lines
IEnumerable<string> filledLines = lines.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(s));

// Add newlines between each line
string html = string.Join(@"<br />", filledLines);
```